# Trouble understanding Permutation Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

I am attempting to work on a permutation matrix problem. I just don't understand where the Unit Basis Vector comes in for this particular problem:

Let p = $$
         \begin{pmatrix}
            2\\
            0\\
            1\\
         \end{pmatrix}
        $$
Compute P(p) $$\begin{pmatrix}
                              -2 & 1 & 2\\
                              3 & 2 & 1\\
                              -1 & 0 & -3\\
                           \end{pmatrix}
                         $$

Could someone kindly demonstrate how problems like these are typically solved. (I did try watching YouTube, but P(p) (lowercase) is always a Unit basis vector/matrix.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz I will edit this message once I get home and I am on a computer.

Comment: I think $P(p)$ might mean $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @saulspatz could you kindly explain to me how you derived that permutation matrix?

Comment: I presume that they are numbering the rows and columns from $0$ to $2$, and I'm guessing that  $p\begin{pmatrix}
            2\\
            0\\
            1\\
         \end{pmatrix}$ means that row $0$ has a $1$ in column $2$, row $1$ has a $1$ in column $0$, and row $2$ has a $1$ in column $1$.  Of course, it might be the transpose of this matrix.  I have no way of knowing.

Comment: You are correct @saulspatz, I re-watched the video from the MOOC I am taking (LAFF - Linear Algebra Foundations to Frontiers) on edX with the University of Texas. I must have been distracted at first. Thank you so much!